# Dynamic Semaphore Request Count

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, semaphore

I've got an ASP.NET application that uses a cache for an API call that is only needed to make one.

At the moment, if I get multiple requests in they all end up hitting the API rather than reading the cache because it takes a while for the request to come back. So effectively I'm getting a cache miss, so in order to prevent this I did:

```
class GetData
{
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim SemaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim( 1, 1 );

    public async Task<ReferenceDataModel> GetReferenceDataAsync()
    {
        this.logger.Trace( "About to hit Reference Data lock" );
        await SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync( );
        this.logger.Trace( "Acquired Thread" );
        var referenceDataModel = await this.GetReferenceDataImplAsync();
        this.logger.Trace( "Releasing Thread" );

        SemaphoreSlim.Release( 1 );
        return referenceDataModel;
    }

    private async Task<ReferenceDataModel> GetReferenceDataImplAsync()
    {
        if ( this.cache.Contains( ReferenceDataCacheKey ) )
        {
            this.logger.Trace( "Returning Cached Response" );
            return (ReferenceDataModel) this.cache.Get( ReferenceDataCacheKey );
        }

        this.logger.Trace( "Making Reference Data API call" );
        var response = await this.referenceDataProvider.GetReferenceDataAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );

        this.AddReferenceDataToCache( response );

        return response;
    }

    private void AddReferenceDataToCache(ReferenceDataModel mappedResponse)
    {
        var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var expirationOffset = currentDateTime.TimeOfDay < this.cacheExpiryTime 
                                   ? currentDateTime.Date.Add(this.cacheExpiryTime) 
                                   : currentDateTime.AddDays(1).Date.Add(this.cacheExpiryTime);

        this.cache.Set(ReferenceDataCacheKey, mappedResponse, expirationOffset);
        this.logger.Trace( "Cached API Call Response" );
    }
}
```

This works by blocking every request as soon as one request has acquired the lock, however, like a mutex it will allow one by one to access the cache...

So the ideal behavior would be, every request is held by a `WaitAsync()` then as soon as the first request has actually resolved the API request, let every request continue (because they'll all hit the cache).

I thought maybe using a `CancellationToken` with the `Semaphore.WaitAsync()` would work, the idea was to cancel all waits so the threads would all continue.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is, but I'm pretty sure the answer will involve a replacing all that stuff with a [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Have you thought about using a reader/writer lock and acquiring an upgradeable read lock, which you uprade to write when you need it? Better even to consider using a lockless cache.

Comment: @Sefe I will look at reader writer lock, that seems like the exact thing I need.

Comment: I believe @JohnWu advice is not to discard at all. If you need to implement an async version of `Lazy<T>` you may refer to [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLazy) by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I am going to checkout `AsyncLazy<T>` now